# AngularJS + RequireJS [ Error Injection ]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

## Introdução

Estou desenvolvendo uma estrutura utilizando o [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) e [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config). Estou começando a estudar RequireJS e pesquisei bastante sobre ele, mas ainda não obtive algo claro dele utilizando com o [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/).

[Github Code](https://github.com/ralfting/angular-require)

#### Problema [ Resolvido ]

Estou com problema em minha dependência no arquivo `app/assets/app.js`na linha 2. Removendo a dependência do angular `'opaApp.application'` ele funciona perfeitamente. Caso tenham alguma critica para melhorar essa estrutura podem falar.

#### Solução

Alterei de `define` para `require` em `app/assets/js/modules/Application/index.js`

#### Problema 2 [ Update ]

Agora com o problema da dependencia solucionada, meu proejto as vezes funciona a chamada do controller e as vezes apenas trava antes. Peço por gentileza que clonem o repositorio e testem e vejam que `as vezes` ele irá funcionar.

#### Problema 2 [ Update 2 ]

O problema está somente no google-chrome. no firefox ele roda redondo.

Comment: Tem alguma mensagem de erro? Falta uma vírgula no `define` do [`Application/index.js`](https://github.com/ralfting/angular-require/blob/master/app/assets/js/modules/Application/index.js#L1)

Comment: Desculpa acabei nao corrigindo a virgula depois de ter mexido. Atualizei o repositorio ali. Obrigado @danguilherme. Pode verificar agora.

Comment: Consegui solucionar o problema de dependência alterando de `define` para `require` em `app/assets/js/modules/Application/index.js`, porém estou com problema no carregamento do modulo. Veja a atualização acima.

Comment: Fiz duas alterações que funcionou: coloquei o arquivo normal do Angular, não o minificado ([linha #4 main.js](https://github.com/ralfting/angular-require/blob/master/app/assets/js/main.js#L4)) e troquei [`define`](https://github.com/ralfting/angular-require/blob/master/app/assets/js/main.js#L16) por `require`, como você fez nos outros lugares.

Comment: Opa, obrigado @danguilherme pela resposta, fiz as mesmas alterações porém ainda continuo tendo o mesmo problema... Essa sua alteração foi feita em cima do meu app?

Comment: Sim, clonei ele e rodei em cima de um servidor HTTP.

Comment: Desculpa, na verdade removi a linha 6 do main.js também!

Comment: @danguilherme consegue dar um `pull request` para mim ?

Comment: Cara, agora não consigo, mas eu colei meu código exatamente como testei aqui: http://pastebin.com/H64Nh1yJ (o main.js foi a unica coisa que eu alterei mesmo). Vou ficar um tempo sem internet, então se eu não responder é pq não vi.

Comment: Aqui notei que funciona perfeitamente no `firefox` e no `google chrome` nao.